# new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I cannot resolve the issue. When application loads react native throw warnings.

```
WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method.
WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the issue related with react native reanimated library. I solve it by uninstalling the library and reinstalling it. Remove all the installation steps of react-native-reanimated library provided by
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#installation.

Simply install  library using command
npm install react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-beta.1

If the issue still then open project in android studio. Go to file->invalidate cache. After it all things work right.

Comment: Error: Unable to resolve module ./Hooks from C:\Users\bdtask\Desktop\Jpo\japyo_v2\Japyo\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\index.ts:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\Hooks(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

Comment: The hyperlink is broken.  For version 2.x, use https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.x/fundamentals/installation.

Answer (score 47):

This is likely due to the newest version of react-native. A lot of libraries still haven't released a new version to handle these warnings (or errors in some case). Examples include https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9882 and https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/pull/501.
If it bothers you, you can hide the warning for now ([source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox)):

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['new NativeEventEmitter']); // Ignore log notification by message
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(); //Ignore all log notifications
```

Comment: Trying to upgrade libraries (when possible) when you upgrade react native is always a good idea.

Comment: This is just removing the issue, not solving it

Comment: Only line 2 `ignoreLogs` is needed. **Update Line 2** :- `LogBox.ignoreLogs(['new NativeEventEmitter()']);`. Edit queue is full... I can not suggest edit changes. kindly update

Comment: @anya is there a way to suppress these in the Node CLI that starts up when I run `react-native run-android`? This suppresses them in the app, but they still overwhelm the whole CLI.

Answer (score 27):

I just add two function to main java module:

```
    // Required for rn built in EventEmitter Calls.
    @ReactMethod
    public void addListener(String eventName) {

    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void removeListeners(Integer count) {

    }
```

Example: for fix warning in `react-native-fs` add functions to `android/src/main/java/com/rnfs/RNFSManager.java` file.

For Kotlin use this code:

```
@ReactMethod
fun addListener(type: String?) {
    // Keep: Required for RN built in Event Emitter Calls.
}

@ReactMethod
fun removeListeners(type: Int?) {
    // Keep: Required for RN built in Event Emitter Calls.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the warning in react-native-fs

Comment: I don't have such file, what should I do?

Comment: I don't know 

Comment: How do you solve this on iOS?

Comment: I don't know 

Comment: WTF. This does work.

Answer (score 6):

same error.

change

```
const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.CustomModule);
```

to

```
const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
```

works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Removing the argument will **break** the event emitter on iOS! From the documentation: `This is required on IOS and will throw an invariant error if undefined.` https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/bae0016dc900b5465d0e714c8d467c1422db9eae/packages/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.d.ts#L40-L41

Answer (score 1):

Expo users:
Upgraded @config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx to version 5.0.0, and the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

1- update your react-native-reanimated library to "react-native-reanimated": "2.0.0"

2- You should update the **babel.config.json** file and add **react-native-reanimated/plugin** to **plugins**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
  ],
};
```

This will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case react-native-location-enabler was creating problem.

just added platform check and executed all the "react-native-location-enabler" specific code just for Android and not for iOS.

This solved the issue.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I had the same problem with the same package. Finally I created two components with ios and android extensions. What do you mean with the platform check? Which was your solution?

Answer (score -2):

If you're using **@voximplant/react-native-foreground-service**, you have to replace `node_modules/@voximplant/react-native-foreground-service/index.js` by

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2011-2019, Zingaya, Inc. All rights reserved.
 */

'use strict';

import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter, Platform } from 'react-native';

const isIOS = Platform.OS === 'ios';
const isAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android';

const ForegroundServiceModule = NativeModules.VIForegroundService;
let EventEmitter;
if (isAndroid) {
    EventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(ForegroundServiceModule);
}

/**
 * @property {string} channelId - Notification channel id to display notification
 * @property {number} id - Unique notification id
 * @property {string} title - Notification title
 * @property {string} text - Notification text
 * @property {string} icon - Small icon name
 * @property {number} [priority] - Priority of this notification. One of:
 *                              0 - PRIORITY_DEFAULT (by default),
 *                              -1 - PRIORITY_LOW,
 *                              -2 - PRIORITY_MIN,
 *                              1 - PRIORITY_HIGH,
 *                              2- PRIORITY_MAX
 * @property {string} button - If this property exist, notification will be contain button with text as button value
 */
const NotificationConfig = {

};

/**
 * @property {string} id - Unique channel ID
 * @property {string} name - Notification channel name
 * @property {string} [description] - Notification channel description
 * @property {number} [importance] - Notification channel importance. One of:
 *                                   1 - 'min',
 *                                   2 - 'low' (by default),
 *                                   3 - 'default',
 *                                   4 - 'high',
 *                                   5 - 'max'.
 * @property {boolean} [enableVibration] - Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate. False by default.
 */
const NotificationChannelConfig = {

};


class VIForegroundService {
    static _serviceInstance = null;
    _listeners = new Map();

    /**
     * @private
     */
    constructor() {
        if (isAndroid) {
            EventEmitter.addListener('VIForegroundServiceButtonPressed', this._VIForegroundServiceButtonPressed.bind(this));
        }
    }

    static getInstance() {
        if (this._serviceInstance === null) {
            this._serviceInstance = new VIForegroundService();
        }
        return this._serviceInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Create notification channel for foreground service
     *
     * @param {NotificationChannelConfig} channelConfig - Notification channel configuration
     * @return Promise
     */
    async createNotificationChannel(channelConfig) {
        if (isIOS) {
            console.warn("ForegroundService may be used only Android platfrom.")
            return;
        }
        return await ForegroundServiceModule.createNotificationChannel(channelConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Start foreground service
     * @param {NotificationConfig} notificationConfig - Notification config
     * @return Promise
     */
    async startService(notificationConfig) {
        if (isIOS) {
            console.warn("ForegroundService may be used only Android platfrom.")
            return;
        }
        return await ForegroundServiceModule.startService(notificationConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Stop foreground service
     *
     * @return Promise
     */
    async stopService() {
        if (isIOS) {
            console.warn("ForegroundService may be used only Android platfrom.")
            return;
        }
        return await ForegroundServiceModule.stopService();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a handler to be invoked when button on notification will be pressed.
     * The data arguments emitted will be passed to the handler function.
     *
     * @param event - Name of the event to listen to
     * @param handler - Function to invoke when the specified event is emitted
     */
    on(event, handler) {
        if (isIOS) {
            console.warn("ForegroundService may be used only Android platfrom.")
            return;
        }
        if (!handler || !(handler instanceof Function)) {
            console.warn(`ForegroundService: on: handler is not a Function`);
            return;
        }
        if (!this._listeners.has(event)) {
          this._listeners.set(event, new Set());
        }
        this._listeners.get(event)?.add(handler);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the registered `handler` for the specified event.
     *
     * If `handler` is not provided, this function will remove all registered handlers.
     *
     * @param event - Name of the event to stop to listen to.
     * @param handler - Handler function.
     */
    off(event, handler) {
        if (isIOS) {
            console.warn("ForegroundService may be used only Android platfrom.")
            return;
        }
        if (!this._listeners.has(event)) {
          return;
        }
        if (handler && handler instanceof Function) {
          this._listeners.get(event)?.delete(handler);
        } else {
          this._listeners.set(event, new Set());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @private
     */
     _emit(event, ...args) {
        const handlers = this._listeners.get(event);
        if (handlers) {
            handlers.forEach((handler) => handler(...args));
        } else {
            console.log(`[VIForegroundService]: _emit: no handlers for event: ${event}`);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _VIForegroundServiceButtonPressed(event) {
        this._emit('VIForegroundServiceButtonPressed', event);
    }
}

export default VIForegroundService;
```

Solution found [here](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-foreground-service/pull/42/commits/4132e4eb091d0e208edbd341f59d3946aaeb39ba)