# new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using quick blox for a text/chat app and using the following for event handling:

```js
const emitter = new NativeEventEmitter(QB.chat);
const  receivedNewMessage = (event) =>{
  const { type, payload } = event;
  // handle new message
  // type - event name (string)
  // payload - message received (object)
  console.log("payload ==>", payload);
  console.log("type ==>", type);
}

emitter.addListener(
    QB.chat.EVENT_TYPE.RECEIVED_NEW_MESSAGE,
    receivedNewMessage
  );
```

This gives me the warning:

`new NativeEventEmitter() was called with a non-null argument without the required removeListeners method`

As a result I am not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69649068/17733413)

TLDR: The QB chat react native library needs updating.

If the QB chat library has been updated you might need to call the `remove()` method somewhere after you have added the listener to stop listening. So save the result of your add listener like so:

```js
eventSubscription = emitter.addListener(
    QB.chat.EVENT_TYPE.RECEIVED_NEW_MESSAGE,
    receivedNewMessage
  );
```

then when you are ready to remove the event listener call:

```js
eventSubscription.remove();
```