# React Native Firebase Auth - NativeEventEmitter addListener and removeListeners Warnings

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I have installed @firebase-react-native/app and @firebase-react-native/auth in my project. When I call `const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);`, I get these warnings in the console:

```
WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method.
WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.
```

I tried to add these functions like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538962/new-nativeeventemitter-was-called-with-a-non-null-argument-without-the-requir) and do `yarn android` again, but no luck. Any idea how to solve this?