# Cannot use RNFS from react-native-fs

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am receiving this errors after importing RNFS from react-native-fs.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes

ERROR Invariant Violation: "ProjectName" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I installed and tried to import RNFS from react-native-fs for creating files and saving some data in it.

Comment: Here is solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69649068/1708333

Answer (score 0):

make sure you import library like that "import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'";