# WARN `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method

Tags: react-native, eventemitter

i have issue when running my apps

> WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method.
> WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.

[image: log error on simulator]

please help me to solving this problem

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538962