# importing usePreventionScreenCapture from expo-screen-capture creates a warning

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, screenshot

In my react native expo application, I am preventing screenshots by using the expo package `expo-screen-capture`. I am also using the dev client to be able to read PDFs so after installing the expo-screen-capture package I had to get a new dev client. By doing this import

```
import { usePreventScreenCapture } from "expo-screen-capture";
```

I get the following warnings :

> `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without
> the required `addListener` method.  WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()`
> was called with a non-null argument without the required
> `removeListeners` method.

if I remove the import statement, the warning goes away but then I can't prevent screenshots.
I know I can use LogBox to ignore that warning but I'd rather have a solution.

Comment: Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69678297/15317992) for your question.